# convergence with comparison test

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n}{n^4+2n+9}$$
Hi guys! I need to use comparison test on this series, I haven't done a lot of comparison tests so far, so I'm not sure what to compare it with. Should I use $$\frac{4n}{n^4}$$ which is $$\frac{4}{n^3},$$ but then I have to show convergence of $$\frac{4}{n^3}.$$ Do I keep comparing until I get to $$\frac{1}{n^2}$$ which I know and shown its convergence at a previous exercise?
If anyone can help me with it, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me. Depending on the text you are using, it may have happened that the convergence of $\sum_n\dfrac1{n^3}$ was proven at the same time as that of $\sum_n\dfrac1{n^2}$. Using that would save you a bit of work, but the comparison also works in your favor.

Comment: TeX-Tip: Leave the punctuation marks inside the double-dollars. Otherwise the end up at the beginning of the next line, which looks strange.

Comment: See how the denominator can be increased, specifically $\frac{4n}{n^4+2n+9}\leq\frac{4n}{n^4+2n}\leq\frac{4n}{n^4}$ and then your logic works. It's always useful to think this way, rather than thinking what one can use to compare. Is this useful?

Comment: $n \gt 4:$ $0<4/n^3 <n/n^3 =1/n^2.$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I don't have the convergence of 1/n^3, but I can prove it. Thanks!

Comment: @Anirudh Bhashyam it is, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

More simply use limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ and since

$$\frac{\frac{4n}{n^4+2n+9}}{\frac1{n^2}}= \frac{4n^3}{n^4+2n+9}\to0$$

we conclude that the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

First we try to bound the series above:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}
&=\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&<1+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \\
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^N(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n})\\
&=1+1+\frac{1}{N}\overset{N\to\infty}{=}2
\end{align}

By [comparison test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-comparison-test-for-positive-series), since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\le2$$

The following series convers:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\tag*{$\text{method (1)}$}$$

---

By [p-series test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-p-series-test), since $p=3>1$, the following series converges:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\tag*{$\text{method (2)}$}$$

---

By [integral test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-integral-test-for-positive-series), since $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3}dx=\frac{1}{2}$ converges, imples the following series conveges:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{n^3}\tag*{$\text{method (3)}$}$$

---

Since $n^4+2n+9>n^4$, then we have

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{n}{n^4+2n+9}\le \sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{n}{n^4}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{n^3}$$

By [comparison test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-comparison-test-for-positive-series), the following series convers:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{n}{n^4+2n+9}=L\text{, where } L\in\mathbb{R}$$

Which implies:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{4n}{n^4+2n+9}=4L\in\mathbb{R}$$

Therefore $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{4n}{n^4+2n+9}$ converges

Comment: We don't have the p-series test in out textbook/course, but this was helpful, thank you!

Comment: @StefanaPausan I made some updates, method $(1)$ is using only comparison test